# An Unexpected Microsoft.net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe

Tags: exception, frameworks, w3wp

Am using IIS7 and the website crashes and the server will show an error message which tells
An Unexpected Microsoft.net Framework exception occured in w3wp.exe

This is a Nop Commerce Based Website

[image: Refer this Error Image]

Comment: There is probably an unhandled exception happening somewhere.

Comment: Hi,This happens when I click  different links simultaneously on the website.
or when i keep he site idle for some 10 min and when i click a link this messag comes

and this application is so big that i dont even no where and when to debug!!!!!

Comment: Have you looked if there are any messages in the Event Log?

Comment: when i check (eventvwr) log was empty

Comment: The issue was because of missing dll's and some nop commerce issue mailing issue